# IOS - Test flight - Beta has expired

Tags: ios, applet, testflight

I create a version 0.1 that contains 2 build:
0.1
0.2

The 0.1 build is expired the 0.2 is the build that I am using to test the application.
I tested with many users different devices and is it working fine.
Someone from my team is getting the error message build has expired.

This user is using 0.2 build.
He uninstalled the app, test flight app and reinstall TestFlight and app.

Do you know where is this error coming from?
Why is this error is happening for 1 user only?

Note: the build has 83 days left so it is not closed to expired.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Anyone faced the same problem ?

Comment: "Someone from my team is getting the error message build has expired." Was that user able to use the app initially?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue as well with a single user getting an error in TestFlight that the beta has expired even though the app hadn't expired yet.

**Solution 1**

Restart the device.

It's kind of hard to believe this is the solution, but when the user restarted the phone the app was no longer "expired."

**Solution 2**

While looking into this, I've also seen [an instance](https://forum.figma.com/t/my-ios-figma-mobile-beta-app-say-figma-beta-has-expired/7455/3) where this issue was caused by the user being signed into TestFlight with a different Apple ID.

> In the Testflight app, you must log in with the Apple ID that you used to download the beta originally (this will likely be the Apple ID that you used to request access from Figma). That should show you the list of apps you have access to, including the Figma beta. If you don’t see the beta after logging in, then you may have to reach out to Figma.

... and throw in a device restart for good measure!